# How to compose mutable Iterators?

Tags: iterator, rust, immutability, lifetime

> Editor's note: This code example is from a version of Rust prior to 1.0 and is not syntactically valid Rust 1.0 code. Updated versions of this code produce different errors, but the answers still contain valuable information.

I would like to make an iterator that generates a stream of prime numbers. My general thought process was to wrap an iterator with successive filters so for example you start with

```
let mut n = (2..N)
```

Then for each prime number you mutate the iterator and add on a filter

```rust
let p1 = n.next()
n = n.filter(|&x| x%p1 !=0) 
let p2 = n.next()
n = n.filter(|&x| x%p2 !=0)
```

I am trying to use the following code, but I can not seem to get it to work

```rust
struct Primes {
    base: Iterator<Item = u64>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Primes<'a> {
    type Item = u64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u64> {
        let p = self.base.next();
        match p {
            Some(n) => {
                let prime = n.clone();
                let step = self.base.filter(move |&: &x| {x%prime!=0});
                self.base = &step as &Iterator<Item = u64>;
                Some(n)                
            },
            _ => None
        }        
    }
}
```

I have toyed with variations of this, but I can't seem to get lifetimes and types to match up. Right now the compiler is telling me

1. I can't mutate self.base
2. the variable prime doesn't live long enough

Here is the error I am getting

```
solution.rs:16:17: 16:26 error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `*self.base` as mutable
solution.rs:16         let p = self.base.next();
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~
solution.rs:20:28: 20:37 error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `*self.base` as mutable
solution.rs:20                 let step = self.base.filter(move |&: &x| {x%prime!=0});
                                                                ^~~~~~~~~
solution.rs:21:30: 21:34 error: `step` does not live long enough
solution.rs:21                 self.base = &step as &Iterator<Item = u64>;
                                                                  ^~~~
solution.rs:15:39: 26:6 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 15:38...
solution.rs:15     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u64> {
solution.rs:16         let p = self.base.next();
solution.rs:17         match p {
solution.rs:18             Some(n) => {
solution.rs:19                 let prime = n.clone();
solution.rs:20                 let step = self.base.filter(move |&: &x| {x%prime!=0});
                                     ...
solution.rs:20:71: 23:14 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 1 at 20:70
solution.rs:20                 let step = self.base.filter(move |&: &x| {x%prime!=0});
solution.rs:21                 self.base = &step as &Iterator<Item = u64>;
solution.rs:22                 Some(n)                
solution.rs:23             },
error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

Why won't Rust let me do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a working version:

```
struct Primes<'a> {
    base: Option<Box<Iterator<Item = u64> + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Primes<'a> {
    type Item = u64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u64> {
        let p = self.base.as_mut().unwrap().next();
        p.map(|n| {
            let base = self.base.take();
            let step = base.unwrap().filter(move |x| x % n != 0);
            self.base = Some(Box::new(step));
            n
        })
    }
}

impl<'a> Primes<'a> {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new<I: Iterator<Item = u64> + 'a>(r: I) -> Primes<'a> {
        Primes {
            base: Some(Box::new(r)),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    for p in Primes::new(2..).take(32) {
        print!("{} ", p);
    }
    println!("");
}
```

I'm using a `Box<Iterator>` trait object. Boxing is unavoidable because the internal iterator must be stored somewhere between `next()` calls, and there is nowhere you can store reference trait objects.

I made the internal iterator an `Option`. This is necessary because you need to replace it with a value which consumes it, so it is possible that the internal iterator may be "absent" from the structure for a short time. Rust models absence with `Option`. `Option::take` replaces the value it is called on with `None` and returns whatever was there. This is useful when shuffling non-copyable objects around.

Note, however, that this sieve implementation is going to be both memory and computationally inefficient - for each prime you're creating an additional layer of iterators which takes heap space. Also the depth of stack when calling `next()` grows linearly with the number of primes, so you will get a stack overflow on a sufficiently large number:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", Primes::new(2..).nth(10000).unwrap());
}
```

Running it:

```
% ./test1 

thread '<main>' has overflowed its stack
zsh: illegal hardware instruction (core dumped)  ./test1
```

Comment: *and with reference trait objects there is nowhere you can store it* - additionally, the actual **size** of the iterator `base` changes as it gets more and more nested. Thus, we need to use heap-allocation so that the size of `Primes` is always constant.

Comment: @Shepmaster, The size of reference trait object does not change, afaik. The only reason it can't be used is ownership.

Comment: The size is indeed constant. Every layer is a box around `Filter<Box<Iterator>, Closure>`, the size of the closure is constant (captures one u64).

Comment: @VladimirMatveev ah, good point. I thought it was a generic type, not a trait object.